# Phyton Os change directory("os.chdir") make work on any pc

Tags: python, module, operating-system

I was developing an Ctkap witch uses os cto manipulate and create directories and now i come to point where i want to upload git hub but i discovred an issue that all paths are specified on my user so i belive that the oschdir function will not work propertly because os will not find my user
on viewrs pc

i tryed to google answers bu i cud not find the answer and jus removing to half of the code but it did not work

I want  to modifi the  chdir
Function to work on any device because the path C:/user/**kryst**/
Change to current user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.